# Javascript not working on Ajax loaded content inside magnific popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="product-action">
    <a href="#" class="btn-product btn-quickview1" onclick="init_popup(<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>, event)"
    title="view item">item detail</a>
</div>
```

I'm new to JavaScript and yet not able to make this working. I have this main_item_detail file, Inside this file I have an item slider that shows some images of the selected item, so when user clicks on specific "item detail" button it opens quick view with magnific popup with the selected item details.

```
    <!-- Start of Quick View -->
    <div class="product product-single product-popup" id="popup_detail_<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>" >
    
        <div class="text-right">
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light" onclick="_prev_id(<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>, event);" title="Produkti paraprak"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light btn-next-product" onclick="_next_id(<?php echo $row["product_id"]; ?>, event);" title="Produkti i radhes"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </div>
            
        <div class="row gutter-lg" id="display_item">
        
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
<!-- End of Quick view -->
```

This is the function that loads the popup with loaded content from ajax in "display_item" div.

```
function init_popup(product_id, e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"popup_item.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{product_id:product_id},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#display_item').html(data);
        //  document.querySelector('#display_item').innerHTML = data; // returns same content
            document.getElementById("item_id").value = product_id;
        }
    });
}
```

This is the popup (popup_item.php)

```
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
    <div class="product-gallery product-gallery-sticky">
        <div class="swiper-container product-single-swiper swiper-theme nav-inner">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper row cols-1 gutter-no">
                <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($images)-1; $i++)
                    {
                        ?>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <figure class="product-image">
                                    <img src="../images/images/gallery/preview/<?php echo trim($images[$i]); ?>"
                                        data-zoom-image="../images/images/gallery/original/<?php echo trim($images[$i]); ?>"
                                        alt="Water Boil Black Utensil" width="800" height="900">
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
                
            </div>
            <button class="swiper-button-next"></button>
            <button class="swiper-button-prev"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="product-thumbs-wrap swiper-container" data-swiper-options="{
            'navigation': {
                'nextEl': '.swiper-button-next',
                'prevEl': '.swiper-button-prev'
            }
        }">
            <div class="product-thumbs swiper-wrapper row cols-4 gutter-sm">
                <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($images)-1; $i++)
                    {
                        ?>
                            
                            <div class="product-thumb swiper-slide">
                                <img src="../images/images/gallery/preview/<?php echo trim($images[$i]); ?>" alt="Product Thumb" width="103"
                                    height="116">
                            </div>
                            
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>  
            <button class="swiper-button-next"></button>
            <button class="swiper-button-prev"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is with the JavaScript functionality. When popup opens, it should be able to navigate the swiper-slide items by swiping and selecting an item, also other functions but it just keeps freezing with no functionality in the JavaScript only the item details (CSS scripts are loaded fine).
I check the console but no errors are reported in the output.

Thank you.

Comment: well you probably need to look at the documentation and look at how to initialize the swiper code after the page loads.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to initialize the swiper code? 
Thanks

Comment: No because we have zero clue what the library is that you are using.....

Comment: @epascarello the library that i'm using is swiper-bundle.min.js and it's not working , any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `swiper.update()` method https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#methods--properties.
Or create a unique ID for each Swiper HTML Structure. And then after loading ajax init Swiper. https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#initialize-swiper