# Swiper not working after Ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm asking this question because of many hours and days of research and still didn't find the solutin of a problem with swiper in my page.

It works fine until I apply a popup to the page (Eg. select an item) and show popup dialog with the ajax loaded content including the swiper.

The popup opens with AJAX and shows only relevant listings, the only problem is that the Swiper Slider doesn't work anymore, in fact, I cannot slide it, it keeps freezing with no functionality.

I think I need to reinitialize Swiper after every AJAX call but I'm not so good at AJAX I'm kind of wondering if anyone can point me into the right direction. Thank you very much.

```
function initSwiper() {
swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
// Optional parameters
  direction: 'horizontal',
  effect: 'slide',
  speed: 150,
  loop: true,
  observer: true,

// Navigation arrows
navigation: {
  nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
},
  
    pagination: {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
},
```

});
}

Comment: When adding content to a Swiper which is already initialised you need to do it via the `appendSlide()` method, so that the events are hooked up, not just by adding content to the DOM. See the docs: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-appendSlide

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you give me a clue on how to do it ?

Comment: Not really, as there's not enough information about what content you're appending in the question. Also, any information I could give you would already be covered in the docs - you just literally call `appendSlide()` and pass the HTML of the slide to add as an argument.

Comment: Do I have to call appendSlide() inside Ajax, like this: $(".swiper-container").appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10"</div>');

Comment: Yes, but it would depend on what the content of the AJAX response looks like. I'd suggest you delete this question and open a new one which includes details of how you're making the AJAX request, what the response content looks like, and what the slides you add need to look like.

Comment: I asked the detailed question here but no answer yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76688491/javascript-not-working-on-ajax-loaded-content-inside-magnific-popup?noredirect=1#comment135207304_76688491